# split string to two substrings from nth occerence of a charactor jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a string like this .

```
var url="http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11"
```

i want to get substrings

```
http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page
```

and

```
5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11
```

i want to split string from the `7 th slash` and make the two sub-strings

how to do this ??,

i looked for `split()`

but in this case if i use it i have to con-cat the sub-strings and make what i want . is there a easy way  ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one:

```
var url="http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11";
var parts = url.split('/');

var p1 = parts.slice(0,6).join('/');
var p2 = parts.slice(7).join('/');
alert(p1);
alert(p2);
```

p1 should get the first part and p2 is the second part

Comment: this works when use parts.slice(0,7) insted of parts.slice(0,6)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex. Generally if your url pattern always follow this structure, it will work.

```
        var pattern = /(\w+:\/\/(\w+\/){5})/i;
        var url = "http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11";
        var result = url.split(pattern);
        alert(result[1]);
        alert(result[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var str = 'http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11',
  delimiter = '/',
  start = 7,
  tokens = str.split(delimiter).slice(start),
  result = tokens.join(delimiter);

var match = str.match(/([^\/]*\/){5}/)[0];
```

Find this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avinapaster/BWQWp/1/)

Comment: i can only get 5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11 . i want the first substring too